# What is the correct value of SHA-512 message-length field if the message length is 3967 bits

Tags: padding, sha-2

In the steps of “Append the padding bits” in SHA-512 system, the message is padded so that its length is congruent to 896 mod 1024. I'm new to cryptography and I can't figure out the difference between message-length field and message length. I'm not sure what is the correct value of SHA-512 message-length field..?

And "The message-length field is used to indicate the actual length of the message, usually in binary form." Right?

Comment: Hint: Read [FIPS 180-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=18), esp. §5.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

> (In [SHA-512,](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=18)) what's the difference between message-length field and message length?

The message-length field is a 128-bit bitstring, when the message length is a (non-negative) integer $\ell$ in range $[0\ldots2^{128})$.

The integer $\ell$ is the size of the message in bits, thus 3967 for a 3967-bit message. That would be 31736 for a 3967-[byte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) (that is [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) in the context) message. An integer has no intrinsic representation or base.

The message-length field is 128 bits, which value is derived from the integer $\ell$ using big-[endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [unsigned binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation) convention. It's first $128-\lceil\log_2(\ell+1)\rceil$ bits first are $0$, which follows from said convention.

> What is the correct value of SHA-512 message-length field if the message length is 3967 bits?

Depending on if we are interested in bits (in binary), expression of these as bytes (in hex) or 64-bit words (in hex):

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111101111111
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0f 7f
0000000000000000 0000000000000f7f
```

---

> The message-length field is used to indicate the actual length of the message, usually in binary form.

I have reservation against this statement: "indicate" would suggest that something or someone would use the length field to find the length $\ell$ of the message, but that's not the case. $\ell$ is encoded in the message length field, but nothing decodes it for the purpose of determining the length of the message. That's not to say the message length field is useless: it's a security feature† towards preventing collisions between messages of different length.

Also "usually" would indicate there are exceptions to the use of binary. That's not the case in SHA-512 or any hash I know. The only variations I can think of (in other hashes) are on endianness, or perhaps counting the length in bytes rather than bits.

---

† There's another feature with a similar goal in SHA-512: the first of "the padding bits" mentioned in the question, which is set to $1$. Since there is also the length field, from a security standpoint, we could do without that $1$ bit. Security would not be harmed, code woudl be simplified, and that would make computation of messages of exactly 120 bytes nearly twice as fast. But that's not how SHA-512 happens to have been specified.